# How to delete all index file in once

Tags: server, cpanel

please tell me how to delete these files at one time, it's making unwanted files on the server and the server has been out of space.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp3oT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go the folder and run the command

```
rm index.html.*
```

Comment: Yes working Thank you sir